# C# simple Proxy and Android phone connection problems

Tags: c#, android, proxy, connection

I got this pice of code from [this Url](https://github.com/MrDesjardins/SimpleHttpProxy/blob/master/SimpleHttpProxy)

this is a simple proxy Server in c#. With my android phone i connect to it like this: (Proxy-Hostname: 192.1.1.24(the IP of my computer) Proxy-Port: 7777). But the server dosn't get any requests. Does anyone know why this doesn't work and why my phone isn't able to connect to the proxy? Btw those two devices are in one Network and i know the firewall isn't blocking the requests.

here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace SimpleHttpProxy
{
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:7777/");
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
        while (true)
        {
            var ctx = listener.GetContext();
            new Thread(new Relay(ctx).ProcessRequest).Start();
        }
    }
}

public class Relay
{
    private readonly HttpListenerContext originalContext;

    public Relay(HttpListenerContext originalContext)
    {
        this.originalContext = originalContext;
    }

    public void ProcessRequest()
    {
        string rawUrl = originalContext.Request.RawUrl;
        ConsoleUtilities.WriteRequest("Proxy receive a request for: " + rawUrl);

        var relayRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(rawUrl);
        relayRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        relayRequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        relayRequest.UserAgent = this.originalContext.Request.UserAgent;

        var requestData = new RequestState(relayRequest, originalContext);
        relayRequest.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallBack, requestData);
    }

    private static void ResponseCallBack(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        var requestData = (RequestState) asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        ConsoleUtilities.WriteResponse("Proxy receive a response from " + requestData.context.Request.RawUrl);

        using (var responseFromWebSiteBeingRelayed = (HttpWebResponse) requestData.webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
        {
            using (var responseStreamFromWebSiteBeingRelayed = responseFromWebSiteBeingRelayed.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var originalResponse = requestData.context.Response;

                if (responseFromWebSiteBeingRelayed.ContentType.Contains("text/html"))
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(responseStreamFromWebSiteBeingRelayed);
                    string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    //Here can modify html
                    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html);
                    var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                    stream.CopyTo(originalResponse.OutputStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    responseStreamFromWebSiteBeingRelayed.CopyTo(originalResponse.OutputStream);
                }
                originalResponse.OutputStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class ConsoleUtilities
{
    public static void WriteRequest(string info)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(info);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
    public static void WriteResponse(string info)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine(info);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

public class RequestState
{
    public readonly HttpWebRequest webRequest;
    public readonly HttpListenerContext context;

    public RequestState(HttpWebRequest request, HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        webRequest = request;
        this.context = context;
    }
}

  }
```

Comment: Is the proxy on your computer listening to 0.0.0.0 or subnet 192.168.1.24/8? Make sure its not only listening to localhost (127.0.0.1)

Comment: How do i change&know that?